# Non-parametric test for comparing four treatments and three times

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, permutation-test

I am working with a dataset where I need to use non-parametric stats (won't go into details). It is behavioral data on captive animals ($n=8$), where $4$ treatments were introduced $3$ different times randomly. I have tested for difference in my repeats using a Friedman test. None were found. I am looking for a way to analyze my data to see differences between the $4$ treatments but also considering difference between individuals ($8$) interacting.

**Questions:**

1. In my mind I should perform a 2-way ANOVA (i.e., the non-parametric equivalent) but most of the tests I have found do not allow for replicated data.
2. Do I average the repeats since no difference was found and then conduct the ANOVA equivalent test?
3. Is there a test that will look for difference in 4 treatments, keeping in mind the individual interaction with replicated data?

Comment: It should be possible to adapt a test to including replicates; it might need a permutation test if you can't get a normal approximation out.